# 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value' when concatenating database fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've a problem with a little query in SQL :

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO #tempTable (Variable1,Variable2) values (''' + Variable1 + ''','''+ Variable2 +'';'
FROM Table1
```

My first variable is a varchar and the second a int. I've a error which say : 
`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value INSERT INTO #tempTable (Variable1,Variable2) values ('00ZZZ','' to data type int.`

The purpose is to have all data in string and then, get back these data in a temporary table on another server.

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: It's not clear what the context is here, but you should definitely read http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: Looks like you are trying to build a SQL string in a SELECT statement, is that correct?

Comment: If you let us know what the ultimate goal is, we may be able to suggest a better strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the error message numerous times I noticed the `+` sign.

The SQL language seems to try to add the `varchar` part and the `int` part to an `int`. I guess you are using SQL Server.

This fails in SQL Server with your error message:

```
select 'abc' + 123
```

You should put a cast around the numeric part:

```
select 'abc' + cast(123 as varchar)
```

So in your case:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO #tempTable (Variable1,Variable2) values ('''
       + cast(Variable1 as varchar)
       + ''','''
       + Variable2
       +'');'
FROM Table1
```

Comment: The first value is not the problem. It's the second one

Comment: Yes for reason unclear to me but which must have made sense to someone, the precendence for SQL server is that if you have a varchar and an int, it will try to implicitly convert to int. Seems to me that it would have created fewer problems had they made the opposite choice for the implicit conversion (ints will fit more often into varchars than varchars fit into ints), but there was probably something in the internals that made it easier to implement this way.